# Leer input del usuario en segundo plano

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, pygame, game

Estoy realizando un pequeño juego en PyGame y me pareció interesante poder agregar habilidades especiales. Estas habilidades deben ser ingresadas por el usuario utilizando el teclado. Por ejemplo, al presionar la tecla Shift, todo lo que el usuario escriba mientras esa tecla está presionada deberá ser guardado en una variable para luego ver qué poder es.
He probado utilizar `sys.stdin.read()` y `event.unicode` para obtener los carácteres, pero sigo sin encontrar la forma en la que deje de leer cuando se suelte la tecla shift.
¿Es posible hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Respuesta

Por supuesto que es posible :D De hecho, hice un código que cuando detecta que uno de los dos shifts fue presionado, empieza a capturar todos los ingresos del usuario y cuando se deja de presionar shift lo imprime en consola:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

# creo un conjunto con las dos teclas.
shift_keys = {pygame.K_RSHIFT, pygame.K_LSHIFT}

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # cuando el tipo de evento es pygame.KEYDOWN, es decir cuando el usuario presiona una tecla...
        if(event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
            # si esa tecla está en el conjunto de shifts
            if(event.key in shift_keys):
                # establesco esta variable que me sevirá para que el programa sepa que se está presionando shift.
                # y la variable con la cadena ingresada la hago vacía para eliminar el ingreso anterior.
                shift_pressed = True
                cadena_ingresada = ""

            # si shift está presionado
            elif(shift_pressed):
                # obtengo la letra presionada y la sumo a las presionadas anteriormente.
                cadena_ingresada += event.unicode

        # si se soltó una tecla...
        elif(event.type == pygame.KEYUP):
            # y esa tecla fue un shift
            if(event.key in shift_keys):
                # establezco en falso shift_pressed e imprimo la cadena ingresada
                shift_pressed = False
                print(cadena_ingresada)
```

#### Errores encontrados

- Si se presionan ambos shifts y se suelta uno, la cadena será impresa aunque haya otro shift presionado.

#### Problemas con tu enfoque

Shift es una tecla que hace que otras teclas devuelvan un caracter diferente. Teniendo mi código que funciona, tendrías el problema, por ejemplo, de que el usuario al presionar números te ingresaría símbolos en su lugar. Por ejemplo 4 se ingresaría como $.

Mi recomendación es que elijas otra tecla, como enter. Y con enter matas dos pajaros de un tiro! Por que enter no está dos veces, por lo que el error de soltar un shift y que quede el otro no ocurriría.

Comment: ¡Funcionó a la perfección! Tomaré en cuenta el cambiar la tecla Shift por el enter para evitar esos problemas tamién.  Muchas gracias :D

Comment: Me alegro c: Es un placer ayudar!